# tomcat 7 can't use jna to load my shared library with absolute path

Tags: java, tomcat, tesseract, jna, loadlibrary

My code:

```
static final boolean WINDOWS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
public static final String LIB_NAME = "libtesseract302";
public static final String LIB_NAME_NON_WIN = "/home/xxx/libtesseract.so";
public static final TessAPI INSTANCE = (TessAPI) Native.loadLibrary(WINDOWS ? LIB_NAME : LIB_NAME_NON_WIN, TessAPI.class)
```

It works on tomcat 6
when I use tomcat 7,it does not work.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract.so': Native library (linux-x86/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path.....
```

I am not authorized to change the jvm Dpath.I also try to use

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libtesseract","/home/xxx/")
```

But it dosen't work too.So what's the solution on this situation?

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: The 99% answer on this is that the security manager has been enabled on tomcat 7, which prevents accessing files outside the application, including the library as mentioned here. The fix is to move the library into the JNA search path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the same jvm architecture??, you can't access JNA libraries between 64bits and 32 bits